# Reducing CSS Code Repetition

Tags: css

I am finding myself constantly reusing various blocks of code in CSS for various elements. One is rounded corners. Example code below:

```
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-khtml-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
```

I've tried 2 different methods to reduce code repetition, which both have cons.

The first is to wrap the code in a class such as .rounded10 and add this class to all the elements on the page that require rounded borders (there's a good 20+). Bootstrap do something similar, but I don't like this method as it introduces unsemantic data into the HTML.

The second is to create a list of elements in CSS that should have rounded borders like:

```
.offers, .welcome, .sidebar, .post {
   ... Rounded corners code here ...
}
```

I'm not sure if this method is even used, I've not seen it.

Are there any other method's I've missed or anything that can help me reduce this repetition in such circumstances. Things get messy especially when you have to use browser vendor properties.

I do not use SASS or LESS, or any CSS frameworks, or helpers such as Compass (although I have). I preferrer to code with vanilla CSS. It's just the way I work. Please no suggestions on using those.

Comment: I don't think there are all that many rules left that need vendor prefixes.  You certainly don't need vendor prefixes for `border-radius` anymore

Comment: @ExplosionPills I wasn't aware of that, border-radius was just an example.

Comment: The second method you propose seems to have the fewest problems, if you're unwilling to use a `.rounded` class. It certainly shouldn't be an issue, and it would make it easier to change all the instances of the corners. The only potential problem is if you want a bunch that have different sized corners. I agree with @Elliot Lings' answer below: there's probably a deeper issue in your reuse, if you're not willing to use a single styling class to accomplish it.

Comment: Also, adding classes to the HTML isn't a problem; that's exactly what they're *there* for. You're not doing anything to the semantic content in an inappropriate way; you're still separating your concerns appropriately. In fact, I think that using `.rounded` is *precisely* the way to solve the problem.

Comment: This is *exactly* what CSS preprocessors are supposed to accomplish. Use one or suck it up and copy-paste. For vendor prefixes, there's [`-prefix-free`](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/), but it makes debugging the CSS in a browser more difficult since it breaks the association between CSS rules and the original source.

Comment: @ChrisKrycho That's a contentious point. Purists argue that using CSS classes that describe presentation is not that much better than using inline styles, in fact one of the main features of Compass is autogenerating grid system CSS that maps to "semantic" class names. That said, it's an approach that's practically useless when making web *applications* as opposed to web *sites*, and thus need to create your own library of widgets with bits and bobs of styling reused between them, which I guess helps make the compromise (`class` being the only presentational attribute) popular.

Comment: It's all about compromising between flexibility of design and ease of development and possible changes in development. It usually works out a lot easier to change some class than mess with your CSS and potentially change multiple elements you did not intend in doing so.

Comment: @millimoose, that's a fair point. I think it probably depends on how thoroughly you embrace an "Object Oriented CSS" approach (which I halfway do, but not the way purists do)—an OOCSS actually argues for the reuse of classes in this way to keep the CSS cleaner; the downside is that it clutters up the HTML. Unfortunately, given the limitations of the media, you're largely stuck with cluttered one or the other. So… go use SASS. That's my preference.

Comment: @ChrisKrycho Don't forget that using a preprocessor to generate fully semantic CSS can lead to (slightly) slower loading times by duplicating style declarations, depending on how often they'd be used if they were a shared class. (Also, the purism involves extra meticulous work.) My aim wasn't to say you're wrong, but that there isn't an unambiguously correct approach here. That said, I like the moniker "OOCSS", it gives the idea an identity beyond "not semantic".

Comment: I really can't see any sense in prefixing something like `border-radius`, which works nicely without vendor prefixes. Was maybe the worst example. Anyway, @Elliot's answer is a  good one.

Comment: @pzin It's as good an example as any, it's as valid to want to avoid duplicating one line of CSS as four. Focusing on the issue of vendor prefixes is missing the forest for the trees here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Other than giving classes for certain features of that element and avoiding a CSS preprocessor there isn't much else you can do.

If you are finding yourself having about 20 odd classes for rounded corner sizes then you should question the consistency of your designs.

There are some great articles on HTML and CSS semantics such as http://nicolasgallagher.com/about-html-semantics-front-end-architecture/ .

I'm not going to suggest you use something like SASS or LESS but I strongly recommend you do so. It will allow you to easily add rounded corner classes and save you time in outputting compressed formats of your CSS.

Comment: +1; this is basically what I was going to write. The only thing I would add is that it makes a ton of sense to just use a `.rounded` class; that's *exactly* the right way to separate concerns not only between CSS and HTML but within the CSS.

Comment: I agree. Embrace the tools that are available to "fix" the flaws of CSS and speedup development.

Comment: @Elliot I will check out that article thank you. I may jump back to using SASS again.

Comment: @Chris +1 for the add. Try to avoid styling HTML but instead pick  CSS classes you want for that element; in the same way you would use Twitter's Bootstrap.

Comment: "I'm not going to suggest you use something like SASS or LESS but I strongly recommend you do so" -- I didn't want to jab you with a comment, but I'm jabbing you with a comment.

Answer (score -2):

One way to trim down css is to use better selectors.  For example if you need to have all `div` in your menu block to have a background colour you could have:

```
#menu div
{
    background-colour:red;
}
```

See [CSS selectors](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/selectorref) at Sitepoint for a good refrence.